# Insert dots at the end of a phrase

Tags: pages, text, formatting

I need some help with a table of contents.
I'm trying to automatically add dots (take a look at red rectangles) at the end of a phrase with the number of the page, as shown in this example image I have found in the internet:

[image]

Comment: What's the issue you're encountering?

Answer (score 2):

To add the dots to your table of contents, select the table, choose the Text inspector, then select the leader as dots.

[image]

If you don't have a table of contents, place the cursor where you wish to insert the table of contents, then Insert → Table of Contents and choose the scope.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but the dots don't appear :/

Comment: @TiS See edit, that should work if they don't appear for you

Answer (score -1):

I just found what I was looking for:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23640?locale=en_US
Thank you all.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Also the solution given in the link is the same solution given in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new around.